# Python - Excel to JSON (manipulation prior to saving as JSON)

Tags: python, json, excel

Found a few postings on this, but none with a solution which solves what I am looking for. I am trying to import an excel file and save it as JSON, but group up some columns under others in the JSON file.

Here is my excel data:

[image]

Here is my python code:

````
from collections import OrderedDict
import simplejson as json

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\Artie\Desktop\animals.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
#
data_list = []
#
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    data['ID'] = row_values[0]
    data['type'] = row_values[1]
    data['name'] = row_values[2]
    data['weight'] = row_values[3]
    data_list.append(data)
#
j = json.dumps(data_list)
#
with open('animals.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)```
````

My JSON result:

```
[{"ID": 1.0, "type": "dog", "name": "fido", "weight": 40.0}, 
{"ID": 2.0, "type": "dog", "name": "max", "weight": 20.0}, 
{"ID": 3.0, "type": "dog", "name": "maxwell", "weight": 10.0}, 
{"ID": 4.0, "type": "dog", "name": "bella", "weight": 50.0}, 
{"ID": 5.0, "type": "dog", "name": "doggy", "weight": 8.0}, 
{"ID": 6.0, "type": "cat", "name": "kitty", "weight": 9.0}, 
{"ID": 7.0, "type": "cat", "name": "missy", "weight": 4.0}, 
{"ID": 8.0, "type": "cat", "name": "duey", "weight": 15.0}, 
{"ID": 9.0, "type": "cat", "name": "louie", "weight": 11.0}]
```

Desired JSON result:

I would like to group each record under the type column, so the results under the dog type would look like this

```
'dog': [
             {
                "ID": 1.0, "name": "fido", "weight": 40.0,
            },
            {
                "ID": 2.0, "name": "max", "weight": 20.0,
            },
            {
                "ID": 3.0, "name": "maxwell", "weight": 10.0,
            },
            {
                "ID": 4.0, "name": "bella", "weight": 50.0,
            },
            {
                "ID": 5.0, "name": "doggy", "weight": 8.0,
            }


        ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I haven't tried this out fully but what you need is an outer dictionary (where type is the key and value is a list of pets of that type)

```
pet_type = {}

for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    data['ID'] = row_values[0]
    data['type'] = row_values[1]
    data['name'] = row_values[2]
    data['weight'] = row_values[3]

    ptype = row_values[1]
    pet_type.setdefault(ptype, [])
    pet_type[ptype].append(data)
```

See if this helps.